# Push a button and get app to respond as a mouse click

Tags: usb, analog

I'm new to putting together a USB board to have a button press and a knob turn send signals to a Win7 PC. I can write windows apps  in VS 2013 using C# but I've never done any hardware work.

Here is what I'd like to do. I have a windows app that uses mouse clicks to push buttons and 'turn' knobs on a photo realistic panel. I'd like to build a box or a panel that has push buttons and knobs I can manually operate and send those signals via the USB port to the PC.

I'm guessing (I'm so new at this I don't know what I don't know) that I would then need to write a small app to listen to the usb port data coming in and decode my own structure of commands and have the app do a mouse click on the screen at the proper location to get the app to respond accordingly.

The above is high level explanation of what the sequence is as far as what I know or think I know, of what needs to be done.

I'd appreciate some suggestions on what components I should buy to start building this setup: USB circuit/device, language/compiler to write any code for this board and what I might use on the client side to 'listen' to the USB data coming in.

I will need to end up with about 36 buttons, 12 rotary knobs and one small 'stick' to move the apps's mouse cursor around its window content.

I should mention that I'm using an app that I didn't write but legally purchased a license for. I just want to operate this app manually with buttons and knobs rather than using a mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Procure an Arduino Leonardo or similar Arduino-alike with native USB support.

Step 2: Talk to the buttons and dials over GPIO, and the computer using [`Keyboard` and `Mouse`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard).

Step 3: There is no step 3. Since you're using the Arduino libraries with a native USB microcontroller the device is presented as a standard HID device and the OS loads its generic HID drivers.

Comment: Then you have the problem of mapping the "mouse" position to the elements on the screen/app. Relative positions are tricky :/

Comment: Step 0: Read *USB Complete* by Jan Axelson

Comment: Gaining a deeper understanding of USB will help if you want to create a custom HID device, but then you'll need to do a bit more work if you still want to use the Arduino libraries, and you will need to write a bit of software to talk to the HID layer.

Comment: >"Then you have the problem of mapping the "mouse" position to the elements on the screen/app. Relative positions are tricky" I'm going to write a calibration routine such that I manually mouse click on the upper left button of the app on the windows screen and note its x,y values. Now my driver app can use that offset to know where every button and wheel, etc. is on the screen. I'll create offset values for all the controls on the screen so all I'll really need to know is the starting point. That way I can resize the window app, move the window, etc. Then do my calibration and be good.

Comment: A bit of code running on the host can figure out where the window origin is and operate it based on the HID reports. Of course, it could just operate the widgets directly in that case.

Comment: What about the buttons and knobs...how would I attach those to the Arduino board?

Comment: Through the GPIOs. There are lots of examples on how to use buttons, potentiometers, and rotary encoders with an Arduino.